# Как вывести круг за границу секции?

Tags: html, css3

Какие свойства CSS использовать чтобы сделать так, как вы видите на макете?[image: ml]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никаких хитрых трюков.
Правда придётся учитывать, что пример с фиксированной высотой.

```css
.pre {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  background: #f13c6e;
  position: relative;
}

.pre .img {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 260px;
  height: 260px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.5);
  position: absolute;
  right: 80px;
  top: -10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 40px rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}

.pre .img > img {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<div class="pre">
  <div class="img">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/SD43J2H.png">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

C помощью `svg`:

```css
svg {
 background-color: #ea3c6e;
 width: 500px;
 height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<svg>
 <circle cx="300" cy="100" fill="#ed7599" r="150" />
 <circle cx="300" cy="100" fill="#f3adc2" r="110" />
 <image xlink:href="https://avatanplus.com/files/resources/mid/578a9bd01f9c7155f570a501.png" x="200" y="30" height="100" width="200" />
 </svg>
```

С помощью градиента:

```css
div {
  width: 450px;
  height: 200px;
  background: radial-gradient(
    circle at 60% 50%,
    #f3adc2 0%,#f3adc2 45%,
    #ed7599 45%, #ed7599, 60%,
    #ea3c6e 60%, #ea3c6e 100%
  );
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот такой вариант

```css
body {
  text-align: center;
}

.shadow {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 3em;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 40px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: relative;
}

.shadow::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; right: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0;
  content: '';
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 60px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="shadow">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/AJ3tUOB.png" />
</div>
```